# Xamarin Forms UWP Observable Collection update is delayed

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm having issues with a xamarin forms uwp application. I have an observablecollection that is bound to a listview. In my view model I have a method that does some calculations and add some messages to the observable collection in a for loop like so.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> myObserableCollection { get; set; }


for(int i = 0; i < length; i))
{
    // Work happens here
    myObserableCollection.Add("first message");
    .
    .
    .

    myObserableCollection.Add("some new value");
    await Task.Delay(delayTime);
}
```

The issue is that the first message shows up, then a blank line, then the first message, then the blank line finally resolves to "some new value". Its like the collection has the the correct number of items in it but it can't show the one right before the task.delay until the next iteration of the for loop starts.

As noted in the comments I have tried to make sure that the collection is being updated on the UI thread by using the following to no avail

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
   myObserableCollection.add("some new value");
});
```

Comment: are you updating on the UI thread?

Comment: I’ve tried invoking the updates on the ui thread and it doesn’t seem to make any difference.

Comment: *”The problem is”* - that’s the last line of question. Were you about to add more information about your situation?

Comment: Add to your question the declaration of the observable collection. Also add the exact code you did to invoke on ui thread.